# Are JavaScript callbacks possible in Plotly or Dash?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I know that `Plotly` to some extent  provides interactivity like changing colours, tabs or using dropdowns to change the plot. But the code must be always written in Python and I can't use there "pure" JavaScript.

I want to create highly interactive, portable, stand-alone HTML pages (no server required) that can be send by email to others, opened and viewed locally on their computers.

So I need that my HTML page contains all the data, manipulates that data and provides interactivity through JavaScript, all on its own.

Is this possible with Plotly or Dash?

Comment: You definitely won't be able to achieve what you want with Dash since it's powered by Flask, which means you'd need a Python environment installed. You'd have more luck with Plotly.js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes this is now possible](https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-v1-7-0-released/31961). However it sounds like you would be better off learning something other than Dash, such as React (a Javascript framework). There are better ways to share an app than through mail though...